# How can I generate *ngFor loop-items inside 1 single div instead of every single item having a div container around it

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi, ngfor

I am creating a text generator that will be used to create a typewriter(something like https://monkeytype.com/). Therefore I have a database with a table with thousands of words. Essentially I want to be able to loop through the table (x amount of times) and then show the words in 1 single div with text inside. Instead a div gets generated for every single word which I do not want.

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-wrap typewriter-text-container justify-content-center">
     <div *ngFor="let words of word" class="typewriter-text">
       <div class="form-control-plaintext" (keyup)="startTypingSession($event)">{{words.word}}</div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

This is my HTML and some TypeScript. I am using Angular.

```
getWordsAmount(Amount: number): Observable<TextsGenerated[]>{
  return this.http.get<TextsGenerated[]>(`${this.ROOT_URL}TextGenerator/words/${Amount}`, httpHeaders);
}
```

This is the GET request I make in order to get the desired amount of words from my table.

**EDIT:**
Since I am trying to create something like monkeytype.com, I want to make sure that all the items that get generated are inside an input tag somehow. I need to be able to register/check that the user types the random words generated correctly.

Result displayed:
[image: 1]

Comment: *ngfor is angular syntax, not angularJS. Are you sure you are using angularjs?

Comment: @cloned Sorry, I meant angular and not angularjs. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you don't want the "div" after the ngFor. Aren't you?

```
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap typewriter-text-container justify-content-center">
     <div *ngFor="let words of word" class="typewriter-text">
       <h1 class="form-control-plaintext" (keyup)="startTypingSession($event)">{{words.word}}</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
```

For this you can just replace the div with a text field, they also can implement some styles and schemas.

Hope this is helpful and sorry if not ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention this (I'll edit my original question/post). Since I am trying to create something like monkeytype.com, I want to make sure that all the items that get generated are inside an input tag somehow. I need to be able to register/check that the user types the random words generated correctly.